# "I would do anything I want" or "I would do anything I wanted"

Tags: conditional-constructions

Let's say I have a question like this

> What would you do if you won a lottery

What's the proper way of answering it?

> I would do anything I wanted

or

> I would do anything I want

Here's another example

> If you were in danger, he would do anything he had to protect you

or

> If you were in danger, he would do anything he has to protect you

Answer (score 1):

The "unreal-past" tense is used with hypotheticals, so *wanted* is correct:

> I would do anything I wanted.

Or

> I would go anywhere I pleased.

Or perhaps the most obvious example:

> I would skip everywhere I go (wrong)
>
> I would skip everywhere I went (correct)

Neither of the second examples really make sense...  *can* and *could* make a better example.  Again you want the past tense *could*:

> If you were in danger, he would do anything he could to protect you

Comment: Thank you for answering! Does the same thing apply to sentences with perfect aspect? e.g. "I'd do what I'd always wanted" instead of "I'd do what I've always wanted"